# Interactive menu in Angular.js with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I just wonder if I can create the interactive menu in Angular.js with Twitter Bootstrap. I just want to express each component as an element of array in app's controller, but not working with repeating code.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cls" ng-init="cls='Blog';" style="display: none;">

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" ng-repeat="menu in menus">
     <li role="presentation" ng-class="cls=='{{menu}}'? 'active': ''">
          <a href="#" ng-click="cls='{{menu}}';">{{ menu }}</a>
     </li>

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
     <li role="presentation" ng-class="cls=='Blog'? 'active': ''"><a href="#" ng-click="cls='Blog';">Blog</a></li>
     <li role="presentation" ng-class="cls=='Info'? 'active': ''"><a href="#" ng-click="cls='Info';">Info</a></li>
     <li role="presentation" ng-class="cls=='Contacts'? 'active': ''"><a href="#" ng-click="cls='Contacts';">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Check out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/za05g7vj/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/za05g7vj/2/).

Issues:

- You should put the `ng-repeat="menu in menus"` inside the li element in order to generate li's instead of ul's.
- `ng-repeat` has its own scope so you need to use `$parent` in front of `cls` inside of `ng-repeat`. Read [understanding scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).
- When working with angular-directives, you don't need to use the {{...}} syntax, you can use the real values. In your case `menu` instead of `{{menu}}`.

Answer (score -2):

You want to generate `<li>'s`, so put `ng-repeat="menu in menus"` in li elements.
Use `parent` instead of `ng-repeat`. Hope that it helps

Comment: What do you mean by "Use parent instead of ng-repeat"?